# MySql - Select * from 2 tables, but Prefix Table Names in the Resultset?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to select * from 2 tables, but have each table's column name be prefixed with a string, to avoid duplicate column name collissions.

For example, I'd like to have a view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW view_user_info as (
  SELECT   
    u.*,
    ux.*
  FROM
    user u,
    user_ex ux
);
```

where the results all had each column prefixed with the name of the table:

e.g.

```
user_ID
user_EMAIL
user_ex_ID
user_ex_TITLE
user_ex_SIN
```

etc.

I've put a [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a14f) that has the concept, but not the correct syntax of course (if it's even possible).

I'm using MySql, but would welcome generic solutions if they exist!

EDIT: I am aware that I could alias each of the fields, as mentioned in one of the comments.  That's what I'm currently doing, but I find at the start of a project I keep having to sync up my tables and views as they change.  I like the views to have everything in them from each table, and then I manually select out what I need. Kind of a lazy approach, but this would allow me to iterate quicker, and only optimize when it's needed.

Comment: Why not alias each of the fields?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I find at the start of a project I keep having to sync up my tables and views as they change.  I like the views to have everything in them from each table, and then I manually select out what I need. Kind of a lazy approach, but this would allow me to iterate quicker, and only optimize when it's needed.

Comment: You could run two separate queries and prefix the keys of each resultset and combine the arrays.

Comment: if that could be done in pure sql, i'd think it'd be something to consider.... can it?

Comment: @TheWestIsThe... have you found the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find at the start of a project I keep having to sync up my tables and views as they change.

Since the thing you're trying to do is not really supported by standard SQL, and you keep modifying database structures in development, I wonder if your best approach would be to write a little script that recreates that `SELECT` statement for you. Maybe wrap it in a method call in the development language of your choice?

Essentially you'd need to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for the tables and columns of interest, probably via a join, and write the results out in SQL style.

Then just run the script every time you make database structural changes that are important to you, and watch your code magically keep up.

Comment: that's a good point... i'll look into that... I'd love a pure SQL approach, but this will work in the meantime... thanks!